# Obligation to circumcise and repeatedly regenerating foreskin

Tags: halacha, brit-milah

[From this related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101115/if-someones-foreskin-grew-back-would-he-need-a-second-bris-milah), we can see that someone who deliberately stretches out the skin of their penis to appear uncircumcised is required to undergo a new pseudo-circumcision, and that, in the case of someone whose foreskin regrew not through their own actions, they may need to undergo a new circumcision to avoid issues of Mar'it Ayin

- Would someone whose foreskin *repeatedly* regrew be required to
  undergo a new circumcision each time it regrew (and if so, at what
  point during the regrowth), even if that means being circumcised many
  times a year for the rest of their life?
- Would there be any difference if the foreskin first regrew as an
  adult (and thereafter started regrowing immediately after healing),
  vs the foreskin starting to regrow immediately after healing as an
  infant?
- If one isn't obligated to immediately recircumcise the infant, when might they start being obligated to be recircumcised? As a Bar Mitzvah?

For the former, whilst the argument about Mar'it Ayin would still apply, it's unclear to me that there isn't a point at which other concerns become more relevant. For the latter, the likelihood of someone who does not already know the details of the circumstances seeing the foreskin seems much lower for an infant than for an adult, so the balance of Mar'it Ayin seems like it may be different

Comment: I don't understand how this isn't still a duplicate. They may not be addressed in the linked answers, but they are indeed asked about in the linked question.

Comment: they are not even slightly asked about in the linked question. The linked question does raise the distinction between a natural and a deliberate regrowth, but does not raise the question of it *repeatedly* regrowing, or of any potential differences in how this might apply to an infant or an adult

Comment: If there were major exceptions to the rules about a regrown foreskin as you posit, I'd reasonably expect a complete answer to that question to address them.

Comment: I'm not positing that they exist, I'm asking whether they exist. As they would not be especially relevant to the linked question as asked in the question itself, it is not unreasonable to think that it is possible they could exist, but that the answerers did not think they relevant enough to include. Additionally, this question here is not just about the rules for regrowing foreskin, but also addresses the argument given i.e. would the question of whether mar'it ayin applies be different for a child vs an adult?

Comment: it's also easy enough to give an answer saying "those wouldn't be a factor, they should still recircumcise and mar'it ayin would be equally likely to apply to an adult as a child" if that's the case, rather than patronisingly insist I, as a layman, should be able to infer that from the *lack* of discussion on another post where it would have verged on off-topic

Comment: See this meta discussion for instance about marking subquestions as duplicates https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3509/759 It seems to me legal distinctions for minors are likely to be mentioned in an answer as relevant. Just like "can a Jew eat rabbit" and "can a minor Jew eat rabbit". Especially regarding circumcision which primarily focuses on minors. This doesn't seem like some obscure edge case.

Comment: you have convinced me now that this is still a duplicate. I will look for relevant questions and if I don't find any, I may formulate another along these more specific lines. Sorry for taking your time, and thank you for the explanation